# Incorporating Python programs into Django

Tags: python, django

What's the best way to do this? Before, I had simply created a text file that Django puts data into and other programs extract from, but now the user needs to be able to actually interact with the program while it's running (via raw_input).

What's the most sensible way to incorporate a foreign Python program into Django? Can it be done without turning it into a Django app?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a command line option ,from the famous `polls` tutorial,

> To implement the command, edit `polls/management/commands/closepoll.py` to look like this:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from polls.models import Poll

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Closes the specified poll for voting'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('poll_id', nargs='+', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for poll_id in options['poll_id']:
            try:
                poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
            except Poll.DoesNotExist:
                raise CommandError('Poll "%s" does not exist' % poll_id)

            poll.opened = False
            poll.save()

            self.stdout.write('Successfully closed poll "%s"' % poll_id)
```

See more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)